# How to add attributes to Jinja2's rendered tag

Tags: flask, jinja2

`{{ form.banner_name }}` will render in my template as:

`<input id="banner_name" name="banner_name" type="text" value="">`

How do I add class `.form-control` to this rendered tag from my template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using WTForms you can pass keyword arguments.

```
{{ form.banner_name(class="form-control") }}
```

This can be used for other things as well.

```
{{ form.banner_name(class="form-control", placeholder="Banner Name") }}
```

More examples can be found [in the docs](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crash_course.html#rendering-fields).

Comment: Could you please show me the documentation for this? Then I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Documentation link added.